# Don't stop on Rails TestTask failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

I'm adding a test task in my Rakefile, similar to this:

namespace :test do

desc "Test lib source"
  Rake::TestTask.new(:lib) do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/lib/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true
  end

end

and then adding (have also done using "enhance" with the same result:
task :test => [ 'test:lib' ]

My problem is that if there is an error encountered in test:lib, the suite stops running.  That's not a terrible thing, but ideally it would go on to run the rest of the suite to let me know that there are more issues later in the suite.

Anyone know how to make it report the errors/failures in test:lib but go on to run the full suite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used something along these lines (minus the "on the fly" bit):

http://toolmantim.com/articles/creating_rake_testtasks_on_the_fly